# select from something, select case then compare

Tags: php, sql

i want to get if a user status has changed in the database

i have this code here

```
SELECT `users`.`status`,`users`.`id_user`,
(SELECT CASE 
            WHEN `timestamp` >= "2013-11-20 15:30:36" 
                THEN 2
            WHEN `timestamp` >= "2013-11-20 15:30:51" 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS `status1`
            FROM `users_actions` as `users_actions`

            ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
            LIMIT 1) as `status1`
FROM `users` as `users` WHERE id_user IN (5,22) 
    AND `users`.`status` != `users`.`status1`
```

it gives me this ERROR 
     `Unknown column 'users.status1' in 'where clause'`

My question is how can i compare an temporary element with a column

Comment: How are you linking users to timestamp? Is the AS status1 after END necessary? I dont think `users` as `users` will do anything.

Comment: yes, it doesnt do anything, but i tried many things i forgot that to take out srry :D .. But how i can get the sql to work somehow ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You subquery has an alias of status1 and your case statement has an alias of status1, so to reference that field outside of the subquery it would be **status1.status1** instead of user.status1

**Update (11/21/2013)**

```
SELECT users.status,
users.id_user,
status1.status1
FROM users as users
,(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN users_actions.timestamp >= "2013-11-20 15:30:36" 
            THEN 2
        WHEN users_actions.timestamp >= "2013-11-20 15:30:51" 
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS status1
        FROM users_actions as users_actions
        ORDER BY users_actions.timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1) as status1
WHERE users.id_user IN (5,22) 
AND users.status != users.status1
```

I updated your query by using the aliases you created to make sure that everything was working. Why create aliases if you aren't going to use them? I also rearranged your FROM statements to see if that takes care of the problem.

Comment: it doesnt work, i changed last line to AND `users`.`status` != `status1`.`status1` and it gives me Unknown column 'status1.status1' in 'where clause'